# Vue plugin not loaded on static site generated by nuxt

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js

In my nuxt.js project I am using a component from a Vue library called [vue-tailwind](https://www.vue-tailwind.com/).

I import the library as a plugin in this way (as advised by the author):

/plugins/vue-tailwind.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueTailwind from 'vue-tailwind'
Vue.use(VueTailwind)
```

/nuxt.config.js

```
  plugins: ['~plugins/vue-tailwind']
```

and the component works perfectly in development.

My problem is that the component is not rendered when I serve the app generated with

```
nuxt generate
```

I already tried to load the plugin this way:

```
    { src: '~plugins/vue-tailwind', mode:  'client' }
```

and also tried to put the component between client-only tag

```
<client-only>
            <t-datepicker
              v-model="date"
              :max-date="today"
              placeholder="Select a date"
              date-format="Y-m-d"
              user-format="d-M-Y"
            />
</client-only>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After several attempt, I understood that the component has to be registered in the plugin. `Vue.use` does not work in generated code.

My final working code is the following:

/plugins/vue-tailwind.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import { TDatepicker } from 'vue-tailwind/dist/components';
Vue.component('t-datepicker', TDatepicker)
```

Comment: How do you pass settings to the component using this method?

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem and that could be fixed by setting `ssr: false` in the  `nuxt.config.js`

```
export default {
    ssr: false,
    target: 'static'
}
```